# How to select all tags in "Export OpenStreetMap topology to SpatiaLite"?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

When selecting fields to convert is there a way to select all within QGIS? I'm currently alternating space bar and a down arrow and this does not seem to be the most efficient method.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention which version of QGIS you're using. I'm using 2.16.0 and this dialog has a 'select all' option:-

[image: qgis export osm to spatialite with select all button]

Not used this function for a while now so I'm not sure when this was implemented, <s>although I'm guessing it's probably in QGIS 2.x.</s> but it seems to have been in 2.10 [according to this commit](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/28a2bf919da3166d518eeedb14cae5ae69e5b649)

I changed to using **QuickOSM plugin** (for small areas) or PostGRES/osm2pgsql (for country-sized or larger) based on protobuf extracts (which are much more compact than .osm xml). These are options if you don't have a specific requirement or preference for osm xml/spatialite.